# Многопоточность Minecraft сервера

Tags: java, сервер, minecraft

Есть сервер Minecraft на ядре Paper, он находится на машине с такими характеристиками:

- i7 3770
- 16 Gb Ram

Тпс на сервере проседает до 15, когда онлайн поднимается до 20 Даже если поставить сервер на Intel core i9 9900k 5 Ghz (Думаю это лучший вариант, если смотреть на один поток), сервер не выдержит онлайна в 100 игроков. **И тут главный вопрос, как можно разделить сервер на потоки?** Если есть другой вариант поднятия оптимизации, был бы рад услышать его.
Искал информацию по вопросу разделения сервера на потоки процессора, но не нашел решений.

Comment: Если в недавнее время ничего принципиально не поменяли, сервера minecraft работают в однопоточном режиме. Только клиент частично поддерживает многопоточность, и то только касательно рендера. Если код не был написан с поддержкой многопоточности, внешними средставми эту поддержку добавить не получится.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, очень поздно оставлять здесь ответ, но хочу сказать одно: Minecraft сервера всегда были и будут многопоточными. То, что сервера работают в одном потоке - полная чушь, ибо при онлайне в 10 человек на 1.18 сервер спокойно может использовать больше одного ядра, а при прогрузке чанков и один человек может загрузить все 4 ядра, к примеру. Многопоточность есть, но она реализована достаточно криво, т.к. 60% кода упирается в главный поток, при котором нельзя запускать на один сервер более 150 человек, иначе TPS будет просаживаться, да и ограничения свои есть в игре. Сервер может начинать лагать даже при использовании 6 ядер из 8, к примеру. Остальные просто будут простаивать.

i7-3770 - не лучшее решение для Minecraft сервера. Лучше присмотреть Ryzen'ы, либо другие процессоры с частотой >4.4 ГГц. i9-9900k с 5 ГГц ныне слишком раскошное решение.

Чтобы решить проблему лагов, необходимо разобраться со сборкой и в принципе разобраться, что там находится. Возможно, ты поставил Bukkit/Spigot, которые ведут себя крайне неадекватно по отношению к производительности.

Comment: Хм, спасибо за ответ. Пробовали ставить i9 9900k и Ryzen 5 3600x, на мое удивление, Ryzen уделал более дорого камня от Intel.